# TcpStream not returning from Read until connection closed

Tags: networking, tcp, rust

I'm trying to implement a simple TCP messaging protocol in Rust with the standard TCP Sockets. The protocol is like so:

```
[C0 FF EE EE] header
[XX XX] type U16LE
[XX XX] size U16LE
... (size - 8) bytes of arbitrary data ...
```

I have come up with the following code:

```
const REQUEST_HEADER: [u8; 4] = [0xC0, 0xFF, 0xEE, 0xEE];

pub fn run_server(host: &str, port: &str) {

    let listener = TcpListener::bind(format!("{}:{}", host, port))
        .expect("Could not bind to the requested host/port combination.");

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        thread::spawn(|| {
            let stream = stream.unwrap();
            handle_client(stream);
        });
    }
}

fn handle_client(stream: TcpStream) {
    stream.set_nodelay(true).expect("set_nodelay call failed");
    loop {
        match get_packet(stream) {
            Ok(deframed) => {
                match deframed.msgid {
                    Some(FrameType::Hello) => say_hello(stream),
                    Some(FrameType::Text) => {
                        println!("-- Got text message: {:X?}", deframed.content);
                        save_text(deframed);
                    },
                    Some(FrameType::Goodbye) => {
                        println!("-- You say goodbye, and I say hello");
                        break; // end of connection
                    },
                    _ => println!("!! I don't know this packet type")
                }
            },


            Err(x) => {
                match x {
                    1 => println!("!! Malformed frame header"),
                    2 => println!("!! Client gone?"),
                    _ => println!("!! Unknown error")
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Read one packet from the stream
fn get_packet(reader: TcpStream) -> Result<MyFrame, u8> {
    // read the packet header in here
    let mut heading = [0u8; 0x8];

    match reader.read_exact(&mut heading) {
        Ok(_) => {
            // check if header is OK
            if heading[..4] == REQUEST_HEADER
            {
                // extract metadata
                let mid: u16 = ((heading[4] as u16) << 0)
                                + ((heading[5] as u16) << 8);
                let len: u16 = ((heading[6] as u16) << 0) 
                                + ((heading[7] as u16) << 8);
                let remain: u16 = len - 0x8;
                println!("-> Pkt: 0x{:X}, length: 0x{:X}, remain: 0x{:X}", mid, len, remain);

                let mut frame = vec![0; remain as usize];
                reader.read_exact(&mut frame).expect("Read packet failed");

                let deframed = MyFrame { 
                    msgid:  FromPrimitive::from_u16(mid),
                    content: frame
                };
                Ok(deframed)
            } else {
                println!("!! Expected packet header but got {:X?}", heading.to_vec());
                Err(1)
            }
        },
        _ => Err(2)
    }
}
```

This is the Python client:

```py
import socket, sys
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", 12345))
f = open("message.bin",'rb')
dat = f.read()
sock.sendall(dat)
while True:
        sock.recv(64)
```

When the program receives a multiple messages in a row, they seem to be processed fine. If the client sends a message and waits for a response, the program gets stuck at reading the frame content until ~16 more bytes are received. As a result, the program cannot send a response to the client.

I can tell it's stuck in there and not somewhere else because the `->Pkt` log line appears with the correct metadata but it doesn't continue further processing despite the client having already sent everything.

I've tried replacing `read_exact` with `read` but it just keeps being stuck there. Once the client software drops the connection the message is suddenly processed as normal.

Is this a design problem or am I missing out a setting I need to change on the socket?

Comment: It looks ok to me. Maybe it is an issue in the client code, that buffers its output? To be totally sure you could try and capture the network traffic with a sniffer.

Comment: @rodrigo -- I have tried with the following simple python program: https://pastebin.com/tUGhBeN9 -- still gets stuck on -> Pkt ... and suddenly goes fine when I Ctrl-C out of python.

Comment: Your code does not compile, something about `reader` being consumed in the `loop`. I'm guessing that this is not the actual code you are running. You should post a MCVE, and also the contents of that `message.bin` you use int he pastebin. Anyway, I fixed the code, added the missing pieces and tested it and it works as expected.